# Avoid Index creation with Entity Framework foreign keys when are part of the Primary Key

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Let's say I have three different tables with these relations:

[ER model picture](http://postimg.org/image/mqjg5b3v3/)

In C# I have the following classes:

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual OptionalUserData OptionalUserData { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FavouriteColor> FavouriteColors { get; set; }
}

[Table("OptionalUserData")]
public class OptionalUserData
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

[Table("FavouriteColor")]
public class FavouriteColor
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ColorId { get; set; }
}
```

And My DbContext is the following:

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OptionalUserData> OptionalUsersData { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FavouriteColor> FavouriteColors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entityUser = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();

        entityUser.HasOptional(s => s.OptionalUserData).WithRequired();
        entityUser.HasMany(s => s.FavouriteColors).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(favColors => favColors.UserId);
    }
}
```

It could be good but it is not, since the generated database schema has unnecessary indexes due to foreign keys.

- In **OptionalUserData** table there is a Clustered index (Primary Key) on UserId field so there is no need of another index (this time non-clustered) on the same field.
- In **FavouriteColor** table there is a Composite Clustered index (Primary Key)  on UserId and ColorId fields so there is no need of another index (this time non-clustered) on the UserId field since I can use the first index to achieve good performance.

[Management Studio schema Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/5f0cpl5ml/)

So, anyone knows how can I avoid those indexes to be created? (So far, I have to delete them after they are created by first time but it is not a very clean solution).

P.S.: I don't have engouh reputation to upload images directly :(

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f9a6152-b7e9-4010-ab96-93459dc23b6b/how-to-prevent-ef-from-creating-an-index-on-a-foreign-key?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Comment: After checking everything out, I have to confess that I have not found the ideal solution for these cases. I mean, if I use EF migrations I can remove the unnecessary indexes BUT from than moment on every change in my model requires of a new migration if not it will fail in runtime. So what I would like to have is just a way to tell EF not to create the index without migrations, something like this: `entityUser.HasMany(s => s.FavouriteColors).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(favColors => favColors.UserId, createIndex: false);`